# Couldn't find executable named RosAria

Tags: rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run the RosAria node in ros hydro and i enter the following command rosrun rosaria RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0
but it gives an error that it can't find the executable named RosAria in catkin_ws/src/rosaria. Even tried rosrun RosAria _port:=/dev/ttyUSB0 which gives an error saying stack/package RosAria not found.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/201291/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-rosaria/) by [hat13](https://answers.ros.org/users/21397/hat13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where is RosAria installed? Is it installed into the /opt/ros/distro directory or in your source workspace?

To use code compiled from source:
source devel/setup.bash inside of your catkin_ws

To use code installed via apt-get
source /opt/ros/${distro}/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2015-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1